# Application Defined or Object Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I am getting this error on the following line of code and cant understand why. Please could someone explain why this is happening?

```
Sub Resource_Details()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

    Set x = ThisWorkbook
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\turnbull\Documents\Global Unmet Demand\3-extract-Resource details.xls")
    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I:O, AB:AJ").EntireColumn.Delete
    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("OFFSET(Sheet1!A2,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),44)").Copy
    x.Sheets("Resource Details").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlValues

    End Sub
```

The error is on this line:

```
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("OFFSET(Sheet1!A2,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),44)").Copy
```

I have used this line of code on the following Macro and it works correctly. I am confused as to why it works on one macro and not the other.

```
Sub Unmet_Details()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = ThisWorkbook
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\turnbull\Documents\Global Unmet Demand\2-extract-Unmet details.xls")
x.Activate
Sheets("Unmet Details").Activate
Range("Table2").Select
Selection.Delete
y.Activate
AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A1:AR1").AutoFilter
Range("A1:AR1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array("Fulfilled", "Requested", "Partially Assigned", "Soft Booked", "Assigned"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),44)").Copy
x.Sheets("Unmet Details").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Comment: `"OFFSET(Sheet1!A2,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),44)"` is not the name of a range, so you can't feed it to `Range`. You could try `Application.Evaluate("OFFSET(Sheet1!A2,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),44)")` which *might* do what you want. You could also try `Application.WorkSheetFunction.Offset()`. The best approach would be to avoid `Offset()` entirely and use VBA to directly find the cell you want.

Comment: Use VBA to define your range in worksheet **y** - rather than attempting to use worksheet functions. `Range.End(xlDown)` might help

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I require it to copy all of the cells from one worksheet to another but the range will change each time. Thats why I was using offset, is that not the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to go about it (note this is untested)

Replace:

```
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("OFFSET(Sheet1!A2,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),44)").Copy
```

With

```
y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(WorksheetFunction.COUNTA(y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")),44).Offset(0,0)
```

And use the offset function at the end to change the range in each loop if that is what you require (I gather from your comment...). You would need a loop though, which your code above doesn't currently have.

Comment: Okay thanks, this code gives the error 'Invalid or Unqualified Reference' on the .Range section

Comment: Ah yes - it should be fixed now

Comment: It now gives 'invalid qualifier' on the .count

Also please see my latest edit to the post :)

Comment: There was a missing bracket. Updated again

Comment: Thank you so much, thats helped a lot :)